# Bootstrap file input still shows all files

Tags: html, file-upload

Even if I write the supported extentions in the accept attribute, there is an option along side with supported types(.jpg, .gif, .png) when browsing, which says " all files(*) " that lists every file type in that directory.

```
<input type="file" accept=".jpg,.gif,.png" />
```

Is there a way to remove that "all files"? Thanks

Comment: This is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```html
<input type="file" accept="image/*">
```

Shows all image files.
But you can't remove **All files** from the file selecting windows dropdown. If you want to restrict certain file types, you need to filter/validate them using a script.

```js
var validExtens = [".jpg", ".jpeg", ".bmp", ".gif", ".png"];   //valid extensions 
function ValidateFile(oForm) {
    var Inputs = oForm.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (var i = 0; i < Inputs.length; i++) {
        var oInput = Inputs[i];
        if (oInput.type == "file") {
            var fName = oInput.value;
            if (fName.length > 0) {
                var validExten = false;
                for (var j = 0; j < validExtens.length; j++) {
                    var tmpExten = validExtens[j];
                    if (fName.substr(fName.length - tmpExten.length, tmpExten.length).toLowerCase() == tmpExten.toLowerCase()) {
                        validExten = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                // if extension is invalid
                if (!validExten) {
                    alert( "Invalid File Extension!");
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
  
    return true;
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return ValidateFile(this);">
  <input type="file" name="my_file" accept="image/*"/><br />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```